# Is it possible to detect whether an Android device is connected to a router?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

The following code can be used to check Ethernet connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
{
...
}
```

If it is connected, there are at least two possibilities:

1. It is connected to router.
2. It is connected to another device (i.e. peer to peer connection)

How can I distinguish one from the other?

Comment: you could also be connected to a router which is only connected to other devices for p2p networking as shown here http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/12/geek-speak-configuring-a-router-for-p2p-networking/ . Telling us why you want to detect that might make it easier to answer. Also if you try to ping a online server i think a router will connect you but a p2p connection will fail. Is my thinking correct? Also do you know the MAC address of the router or the devices?

Comment: @Shreyans The device has two scenarios: connecting to a computing device (P2P) and connecting to a router (i.e. AP).  The app performs different tasks for these two scenarios.  Instead of asking the user to specify the scenario, we prefer detecting it automatically.

Comment: ok so in the P2P case online API calls will always fail correct?

Comment: @Shreyans could you give an example of online API calls?  BTW, connecting to a router does not necessarily mean that internet connection is available. It could be a closed LAN.

Comment: well that is exactly the point i raised in the first comment, p2p connection can be over a wifi router too. And an example of online API call would be a Volley request to your hosted web server going to onErrorResponse. ie you wont be able to communicate with your online server. p2p only means that there is not a central server, though any number of routers can exist i think. so really router and p2p connection are not mutually exclusive. Thats why i asked what are you trying to accomplish here , maybe there is another metric you could monitor

Comment: @Shreyans  OK.  I got your point - the answer to my question is: impossible.  I can accept this as the answer if there is no alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106871/discussion-between-shreyans-and-hong).

Answer (score 0):

the code as follow:

```
public static int getNetWorkType(Context context) {  

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();  

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {  
        String type = networkInfo.getTypeName();  

        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {  
            mNetWorkType = NETWORKTYPE_WIFI;  
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {  
            String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();  

            mNetWorkType = TextUtils.isEmpty(proxyHost)  
                    ? (isFastMobileNetwork(context) ? NETWORKTYPE_3G : NETWORKTYPE_2G)  
                    : NETWORKTYPE_WAP;  
        }  
    } else {  
        mNetWorkType = NETWORKTYPE_INVALID;  
    }  

    return mNetWorkType;  
}
```

note: the hotpoint is also  wifi

Comment: Type MOBILE is for the device's cellular radio, not WIFI P2P.

Comment: the OP wants to differentiate between types of WIFI connections, not between WIFI and mobile connection as you have shown

Comment: @Shreyans No, I want to differentiate two types of Ethernet connection (via Ethernet cable), not Wi-Fi connection. Nevertheless, thank you for pointing out the answer does not answer my question.

Comment: wait i dont understand, how do you connect an ethernet cable to a mobile? or are you developing for some other device like a TV maybe? can you explain a little more please

Comment: @Shreyans without distracting you into irrelevant details, let me just give an example of getting Ethernet connection - USB-to-Ethernet adapter.

Comment: @A.Liu, thank you for trying to help me though it does not answer my question.

Comment: @Hong ok now i understand, i actually didnt know that could be done! im new to android